# Error while connecting Ubuntu server from a client

Tags: ssh

1. installed the openssh server in virtualbox using

   ```
   sudo apt-get install openssh-server
   ```
2. tried to connect the installed server in virtual machine from the main ubuntu terminal using the command:

   ```
   ssh computer name of the main machine@system name of the virtual machine
   ```

   firstly the result was:

   ```
   ssh: connect to host nirmal port 22: Connection refused
   ```

   then tried to open the port by using the command:

   ```
   sudo ufw allow 22
   ```
3. I tried the problem number 2 with the ip address of both the systems. The ip address of the main system was 192.168.100.106 and the ip of the virtual machine was 10.0.2.15.
   tried to connect the systems using the command:

   ```
   ssh 192.168.100.106@10.0.2.15
   ```

   when the enter key was pressed the command goes to the next line without any output and the cursor keeps blinking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't connect using the ip of the client you connect using a user account that is set up on the server, that has also been granted the right to establish a ssh connection. 
Then you connect (from the client) with `ssh <user name of account on server>@<server ip>`

Comment: Here is a detailed guide published by Ubuntu...https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/openssh-server.html